# Custom ImageView with rounded corners not working on some Android devices

Tags: java, android, imageview

I'm using this custom ImageView class to basically simulate an image having rounded corners:

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class CustomImageView extends ImageView {

    public static float radius = 18.0f;

    public CustomImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public CustomImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        Path clipPath = new Path();
        RectF rect = new RectF(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
        clipPath.addRoundRect(rect, radius, radius, Path.Direction.CW);
        canvas.clipPath(clipPath);
        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }
}
```

and this is the usage:

```
    <com.example.sixerstrivia.CustomImageView
        android:id="@+id/customIV"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/button_background" />
```

This worked on another device I had previously which was running Android 3.x.x. I'm running it now on Android 4.2.2 and the corners are no longer rounded. My question is: what is causing this not to work on my current device running 4.2.2? And is there a way to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: Since this has already been implemented in [this library](https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView) and [this library](https://github.com/pungrue26/SelectableRoundedImageView) and [this library](https://github.com/siyamed/android-shape-imageview) and [this library](https://github.com/Pkmmte/CircularImageView) and [this library](https://github.com/vinc3m1/RoundedImageView), you might consider just using one of those libraries. Or, see how they do it, to help you with your own implementation.

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks for the resources, will check them out

Comment: I'm having the same issue as well on samsung s2 running jellybeans 4.1.2.
Although there are many libraries that do image rounding, sometimes you work on some one else's project trying to fix bugs, and your looking for some immediate solution, so still it would be nice to know if some one came up with something about it.
@CommonsWare Thanks for pointing out the links for the libraries, it's very helpful.